# wget does not follow Internet page redirection

Tags: networking, wget, redirection, web

For a concrete example of the problem, when I go to the following address in a regular browser:

```
http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/SOCS/SOCS16/paper/viewFile/13951/13240
```

I get re-directed to `https` that contains a PDF file:

```
https://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/SOCS/SOCS16/paper/viewFile/13951/13240
```

However, when I do:

```
wget http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/SOCS/SOCS16/paper/viewFile/13951/13240
```

the redirection does not happen and the PDF is not fetched. Note that this happens during the execution of a script, in which I only have the `http` address. Is there a way to make `wget` follow this re-direction and fetch the file?

Comment: That site uses a type of redirect that wget doesn't support. But why can't you just change `http` to `https` before downloading e.g. with `sed 's/http:\/\//https:\/\//g'`?

Comment: When a user of my script requests an article, it looks for the link in Google Scholar. Thus, my script may need to fetch articles from many different cites, not only `aaai.org`. So, the re-direction may include other changes in the address, not only from `http` to `https`. Hence, I need a general solution.

Comment: You may want to use a different language for this e.g. python and then you write some code for handling the redirect yourself.